# R: Reading multiple text files from a folder in windows

Tags: r

I am trying to read a list of text files from a windows folder in R. However I am not able to read it.

Here is the code that i did:

```
pathname <- "E:/ISG/Training/"
testing_file_names <- paste0(pathname,"testing")
testing_files <- list.files(testing_file_names)

print(testing_files)
```

When i tried to read the files this is the issue:

```
> print(testing_files)
character(0)
```

I am not sure what mistake i am doing. Please help.

Comment: What does the directory listing for `E:/ISG/Training/testing` look like?

Comment: Do you have any files in `E:/ISG/Training/testing`? If so, what kind of file are these? (.csv, .xlsx, etc)

Comment: Just a note, when you're constructing file or folder paths, instead of using `paste0(pathname,"testing")`, it's generally a good idea to use `file.path(pathname,"testing")`. Shouldn't be a problem here AFAIK, just a bit more robust in general.

Comment: @miken32 - it contains text files

Comment: @nate.edwinton - yes, it has text files

Comment: @rosscova - Thanks for the suggestion